# Simple web server in Scala

Tags: scala, webserver, embeddedwebserver

I need a Scala library that provides me a very simple web server.

I need it to provide json content to a web user interface for an application I'm developing so it should be able to return both static pages and generated jSON data.

I saw that there are a lot of web frameworks, but they seem an overkill for what I need to do.

Comment: [BlueEyes](http://noelwelsh.com/blueeyes/intro.html) perhaps?